# Only default controller is working and the rest is 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller

I'm using codeigniter on my wamp and everything is fine but when I upload it on live server the default_controller is working but the other controller are 404 not found or "The requested URL /Sample_controller was not found on this server".

Here is my sample controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Sample_controller extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        print_r('Hello World');
    }
}
```

and here's my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

and this is my router.php:

```
$route['default_controller']    = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

and my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.sampleurl.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$


    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|user_assets|tmp|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

if I tried this sampleurl.com it's working fine and will direct me to my default controller which is the login but if i tried this sampleurl.com/sample_controller or sampleurl.com/login it will lead me to 404 not found The requested URL /sample_controller was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at sampleurl.com Port 80

I hope someone can help me on this
I tried changing them to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = AUTO
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

and it's still not working.

Comment: did you save your controller on your server with leading uppercase?

Comment: Yup I already change it to uppercase and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a route for that controller to work

```
$route['sample_controller']    = 'sample_controller';
```

For every new controller you create you need to have a route for it

Comment: change to  $route['sample_controller']    = 'index.php/sample_controller';

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite installed on your local server?

Comment: i'm using wamp server on my local server. it's working on my local server but it's not working on my live server

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you may have these 2 issues:

1- As per [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) you are required to make your controller filename first character Uppercase.

2- Try adding a question mark "?" in your .htaccess file's last rule. Also remove the "/" before "index.php" check the code below.

**Current code:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**New code:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @irish try adding a / infront of index.php like this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Just simply change

```
RewriteBase /folder
```

This line of code in your .htaccess file to appropriate folder name of your project and it will work fine.